# Start EXE Through Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, I'm trying to setup a basic script to install WinRAR (as my test, others later on) and I' can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I have:

```
@ECHO OFF

    IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR" GOTO End
    IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\WinRAR" GOTO End

    IF DEFINED ProgramFiles(x86) (
        START C:\WinRAR_4.20_(x64).exe
    ) ELSE (
        START C:\WinRAR_4.20_(x86).exe
    )

:End

    PAUSE
```

The first two `EXIST` checks work fine, but I can't get the `START` command to work. If I just type it out in the CMD window it starts up the installer, but it just wont do it from the batch file.

Can someone point me to where I'm screwing up?

Comment: Do you see any error messages when running the CMD file?

Comment: @aphoria I don't get any error messages. The CMD window just opens for a split second and disappears again.

Comment: Instead of double-clicking the CMD file, open a command prompt and then run your CMD from there. Then you will be able to see any errors that occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the FileName. Get rid of parenthesis in the file name and it should work fine. WinRAR_4.20_x64.exe and WinRAR_4.20_x86.exe

Comment: Please check if any of these folder present or not?
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR
and 
C:\Program Files\WinRAR

if any of them present. it will hit the :END which does nothing.

Comment: Copied and pasted word for word, still nothing. Could my computer be blocking it somehow? Not sure if this matters, but I'm Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Just a guess. Try to run the console as an Administrator. You probably don't have install access. I have checked this on a windows 7 64 bit PC and it went well.

Comment: Well, silly me, I actually still had a WinRAR installation folder in one of the directories and the check was just sending the script to the :End... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

the `start` command requires a string for the title of the window, for instance,

`start "" apples.exe`

will start `apples.exe` with the title of the console window as

currently you are telling the start script that the title of the console window should be:
`C:\WinRAR_4.20_(x64).exe`

You should type in the following:

`start "" "C:\WinRAR_4.20_(x64).exe"`

Comment: I changed it to `START "" C:\WinRAR_4.20_x64.exe`, but it still isn't working.

Comment: why did you remove the parenthesis? you need the exact file name, if you're worried about it being interperated as syntax use `"filename"`

Comment: I renamed the files per @Tariqulazam's suggestion.

Comment: That suggestion was wrong, I see no documentation stating that his answer is correct.

Comment: `start` only requires a title ***if*** the parameters have spaces, in this case it doesn't.

Comment: @BaliC you seem to be correct, I've always been slapped when not putting the title in though, so I assumed this was the case, It seems like best practice to input a blank title for clarification however.

Comment: @Serdalis Yeah I think it is a good habit to give it a blank title and quote everything, that way you don't get stung when your spaced parameter's don't work! :)

Answer (score 0):

It worked on first time only.Non of this options.

1. start "" C:\Program Files (x86)\MSI\Command Center\CommandCenter.exe
   2)START /d start "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSI\Command Center" CommandCenter.exe

Comment: Hi. Please note that this question is very old (2012) and already has accepted answer, meaning that the question is solved. Please don't revive old posts.